# OpenFileDialog using Prism MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I am using Prism 6.1 to implement the MVVM pattern. For notification/confirmation dialogues I am using InteractionRequest and InteractionRequest as detailed on the Advanced MVVM Scenarios Using the Prism Library page on msdn. My question is how can I start using OpenFileDialog within MVVM. Prism doesn't provide something similar for Save and Open dialogues. Can you please give me an example of the code that should be incorporated in the View & ViewModel. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

YOU need to simply create a dialog service.

```
public interface IDialogService
{
    void Show();
}

public class DialogService : IDialogService
{
    public void Show()
    {
        //logic to show your dialogs
    }
}
```

Make sure to register it with your container:

```
Conatiner.Register<IDialogService, DialogService>( do you want a singletone?);
```

Then ask for it in your ctor

```
public ViewAViewModel(IDialogService ds) { ... }
```

Now call it whenever you want.

Comment: Hi Brian, I am a big fan! Do I need to type any code in the View for exchanging msgs with the VM? Something like the InteractionRequestTrigger (in the View) which is bound to a NotificationRequest property in VM? And will I always need to use the mediator pattern along with the dialog service? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you just want to show your dialog using the service, expose a Command and in the Execute, call dialogService.Show

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. I thought that all message and dialog boxes should be handled by the UI layer?! For example, when the VM needs to show a message box, all I need to do, is raise an event (from the VM) which will trigger the InteractionRequestTrigger in the UI layer (the View). But now, if I need to show an open dialog box from the VM, I will just call dialogService.Show() from the VM. i.e. there is no interaction between the VM and the VIew here, the VM will just use the service to show the open dialog box, right? Thanks.

Comment: You're wrong :).  As long as you abstract away the actual implementation using an interface, you can show any dialog you want from a VM.

Answer (score 0):

I for one use a dedicated TriggerAction for that.

```
public class SelectFileAction : TriggerAction<FrameworkElement>
{
    protected override void Invoke( object parameter )
    {
        ISelectFilePayload payload = notification.Content as ISelectFilePayload;

        // Configure the open file dialog
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.Filter = payload.Filter;

        // Show the dialog 
        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

        // Process dialog result
        if (result == true)
        {
            // Return the name of the selected file in the payload
            payload.Path = dlg.FileName;

            // The Callback property, if set, contains the invoker's callback method
            var callback = args.Callback;

            // Call the invoker's callback if any
            if (callback != null)
            {
                callback();
            }
        }
    }
}
```